# Store derived object in vector of base type

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, derived

I have a std::vector of pointers of a base class type:

```
vector<Base*> baseList;
```

And I push a derived class type onto the vector:

```
Derived* derivedObject = new Derived();
baseList.push_back(derivedObject);
```

But when I iterate the list and call the function which is overridden from the base class by the derived class the code in the derived class isn't called. Am I using the vector in the correct way?

My base class has uses the virtual keyword before declaring its functions and the derived class derives the base class with:

```
class Derived : public Base
```

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:

To call the function I have declared:

```
typedef vector<App*>::iterator AppIterator;
AppIterator begin() { return l_Apps.begin(); }
AppIterator end()   { return l_Apps.end(); }
```

And I call the function like so:

```
for (AppIterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
{
    (*it)->Initialize();
}
```

Could the problem be here?

Comment: Looks fine to me. How are you calling the function?

Comment: Please double-check that the function you are attempting to call is marked `virtual`.

Comment: Need more details. Do a mockup with minimal(ish) base and derived clases, and check if you can repeat the problem. If not, compare with your real use to see why; if yes, report here.

Comment: I agree with Kevin Ballard.  Make sure that your derived class is also using the virtual key word for its function.

Comment: [Working demo](http://ideone.com/cuDCuD).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: `warning: comparing signed and unsigned integer values`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: And nothing ;)

Comment: What are the access modifiers for your virtual function in both classes?

Comment: public. I cant see anything wrong from looking at the working example you posted. I'm working with Marmalade SDK (compiling x86) but could this be the reason?

Comment: Still awaiting your testcase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the thing with iterator... this code works fine for me, so if your problem persists, consider different compiler =)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "Base\n";
    }
};
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*> s;
    s.push_back(new Base());
    s.push_back(new Derived());
    s.push_back(new Base());
    s.push_back(new Derived());
    s.push_back(new Base());
    s.push_back(new Derived());
    for (std::vector<Base*>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->f();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output I have:

```
Base
Derived
Base
Derived
Base
Derived
```

---

also you might try to cast the pointers by [`dynamic_cast<>`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/keyword_dynamic_cast.htm), even though it defeats the whole point of using virtual methods. Good luck.